# PETS 2006 Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, database

Does anybody have a copy of PETS 2006 Benchmark Data (or maybe you know, where can it be downloaded from)? Can you please share it? Their hosting seems to be down (both http and ftp. maybe, just this dataset not available anymore).

Dead links to the Dataset: http://www.cvg.reading.ac.uk/PETS2006/data.html ftp://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/pub/PETS2006/

**Update:
Shared the database, will keep it available as of now**: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F3xAgdcmCZNEWpJY_HQkWcQneWvMg7xo

Comment: the given sites are all unreachable at the moment...
does someone still have a copy ?

Comment: Uploaded, will keep the Dataset available for a couple of weeks, at least: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F3xAgdcmCZNEWpJY_HQkWcQneWvMg7xo

It would be nice to find a suitable place to upload the Dataset there.

Comment: @Aram maybe this is a good case for a torrent, because the files are 100% static

Comment: Maybe, but it may end up relying on 1 or 2 seeders...

Comment: I Cannot download from the following link: ftp://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/pub/PETS2006/ ftp://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/pub/groups/cvg/PETS2006/ http://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/PETS2006/ Could you help us to get dataset?

Comment: It is still available through the gdrive link I've posted. I'm not going to delete it as for now

Comment: (Please move to comment, thanks a lot) Thanks a lot **Aram** with the google drive link, Do you have [PET 2007](https://www.cvg.reading.ac.uk/PETS2007/data.html)) or [AVVS 2007](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~andrea/avss2007_d.html), I want to get dataset about Abandoned Bag All dataset link is unreadable.... Thank you very much again for Aram

Comment: I only found PETS2009 http://www.milanton.de/data/

Comment: @Aram can you post your gdrive link to collect the bounty?

Comment: @philshem, I'm not sure I understand what kind of gdrive link are you speaking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sites are working for me:

ftp://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/pub/PETS2006/

ftp://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/pub/groups/cvg/PETS2006/

Not working:

http://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/PETS2006/

So you'd have to replace the links in the documentation page with one of the two working sites above, or just manually download the specific files.

---

From the documentation page:

> The scenarios can also be downloaded from ftp://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/pub/PETS2006/ (use anonymous login). Warning: ftp://ftp.pets.rdg.ac.uk is not listing files correctly on some ftp clients. If you experience problems you can connect to the http server at http://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/PETS2006/.

Comment: Thanks a lot. http://ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/pub/PETS2006/ works. Don't know why, but both of the ftp links you've mentioned don't work over FileZilla ftp client.

Comment: Duh. I meant http: //ftp.cs.rdg.ac.uk/pub/PETS2006 works.

Comment: If the FTP link works with the browser/explorer but not Filezilla, it could be a proxy problem. Anyway, for a couple zipped files, using the browser is easy enough.