# PETS 2007 Dataset

Tags: machine-learning

Does anyone know if the PETS 2007 Dataset (http://www.cvg.reading.ac.uk/PETS2007/data.html) is still available anywhere? Their FTP server and HTTP server seem to not be working.

Comment: are any of the resources from the PETS2006 answer of use? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12412/1511

Comment: Unfortunately not, the Google drive link there works for 2006 though but no mention of 2007.

Comment: In this case I'd contact them, and ask about mirrors - or making a copy at archive.org

Comment: I only found PETS2009 http://www.milanton.de/data/

Comment: did you manage to get the data of PETS2007 ?